# Constrain values of an array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to constrain the values of a numpy array so that no values lie between -0.5 and 0.5. So if I had an array shaped (6,2) with values like this:

```
array([[  0.49873803,  -1.66316398],
       [ -0.36091764,   2.0635736 ],
       [ -1.09922111,  -2.49380792],
       [  0.92724579,  -5.19540319],
       [  1.49726584,  -0.22718924],
       [ 60.        ,  60.        ]])
```

How can I get numpy to change the values that are from -0.5 -> 0.0 to be -0.5, and 
from 0.5 -> 0.0 to be 0.5 so that the example array would be:

```
array([[  0.5,  -1.66316398],
       [ -0.5,   2.0635736 ],
       [ -1.09922111,  -2.49380792],
       [  0.92724579,  -5.19540319],
       [  1.49726584,  -0.5],
       [ 60.        ,  60.        ]])
```

I tried using np.clip but that didnt work, or I couldn't figure it out, so here I am!

Answer (score 6):

For your `a` just run:

```
a[( 0.  <= a) & (a < 0.5)] =  0.5
a[(-0.5 <  a) & (a < 0. )] = -0.5
```

or simply:

```
np.putmask(a, np.abs(a) < .5, np.sign(a) * .5)
```

The first one can be adjusted to handle `0.` according to your needs. The second one leaves it to `0.`

Comment: I think `a[(0.5 > a) & (a >= 0)] = 0.5` looks cleaner.  (OP should also decide how to handle 0, I guess.)

Comment: I like the usage of `putmask()`.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried just iterating through the Array?

```
i = 0
j = 0

while ( i < len(A)):
    while (j < len(i)):
        if  -0.5 <= A[i][j] <= 0:
            A[i][j] = -0.5
        if  0 <= A[i][j] <= 0.5:
            A[i][j] = 0.5
        j = j + 1

    i =  i +1
```

Or something like that... forgive me if the syntax isn't all right...

Comment: Numpy arrays are not made for iteration.